# TreeMap duplicates keys and doesn't put values

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

f is a LinkedList with different words of a text in it.I am trying to analyze the list and put everything in a TreeMap (m) with the words as key and the amount of it appearing as the value.
My code is working somehow but not 100%. It is for example producing an output (m) e.g "Er"=6 , Er   Here the second "Er" doesn't have a value assigned and it doesn't get added to the first "Er" key somehow.

```
 public void analysiere(){
    int value=1;
    for(String word: f){
        int check=0;
        if(Character.isAlphabetic(word.charAt(0))){

            for(String schlüssel: key){
                if(word.equals(schlüssel)){
                   m.put(schlüssel,m.get(schlüssel)+1);
                   check=1;
                }
            }
            if(check==0) {
                m.put(word, value);
            }


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What is a "key" variable in your code?

Comment: Set<String> key=m.keySet(); it is the keySet for the map

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify your code a bit:

```
public void analysiere(List<String> words, Map<String, Integer> m) {
    for (String word : words) {
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(word.charAt(0))) {
            if (m.containsKey(word)) {
                m.put(word, m.get(word) + 1);
            } else {
                m.put(word, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need the `check` variable, because you already checking the same logical condition using `if` operator.

Comment: Hey there thanks for your answer ! I was using the check variable because if was iterating through key and therefor couldn't change it(Thats what the compiler said). Your code gives me the exact same output as my code does. The problem is still there :/

Comment: @DiesDasAlex, can you add the example "wrong" output to the original question? I believe there is a problem with charsets/alphabets somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't understand your code - try to answer @Sergey's question.
The easiest way I can think of to do what you described would be something like:

```
f.stream()
.filter(word -> Character.isAlphabetic(word.charAt(0)))
.forEach(word-> {
Integer currentNumber = m.getOrDefault(word,0);
currentNumber++;
m.put(word, currentNumber);
});
```